# C++ for loop and switch statement logic error

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

In this loop (assuming `amount` is 2), instead of printing:

```
1. [op1]
2. [op2]
```

it prints:

```
1. [op1]
2. [op2]
3. [op3]
4. [op4]
5. [op5]
```

Why? How can I fix this?

```
for(int i=1;i<=amount;i++){
            //string s;
            switch(i){
            case 1:
                cout << i << ". " << op1 << endl;
                //s = op1;
            case 2:
                cout << i << ". " << op2 << endl;
                //s = op2;
            case 3:
                cout << i << ". " << op3 << endl;
                //s = op3;
            case 4:
                cout << i << ". " << op4 << endl;
                //s = op4;
            case 5:
                cout << i << ". " << op5 << endl;
                //s = op5;
            }
            //cout << i << ". " << s << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Think of switch as a glorified `goto`: it jumps to a case and just goes from there, as if the case were a label and the label was selected by the `switch` expression. To stop execution, use `break;` at the end of the case.

Comment: You should actually get `[op1] [op2] [op3] [op4] [op5] [op2] [op3] [op4] [op5]`, right?

Comment: @Vlad - yes, that's what OP should get.

Comment: This looks similar to Duff's Device: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `break;` or `switch()` will have what's called `"fallthrough"`.

(This means that it executes your case: and then continues on anything that comes afterwards, including code in other case statements).

Answer (score 2):

You need to put

```
break;
```

at the end of each case. Otherwise it goes to case1, and then continues through to the end of the select. (case1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert `break;`-statements at the end of each of your `case:`-parts.

This is because `switch () {}` is merely a reformulation of a `goto`, the cases are just labels, not real blocks (that's why they use the label-syntax instead of a block-syntax like `case ... { }`.

Answer (score 1):

Put a "break" statement after the cases, otherwise the control flow will just go straight through.